# printing function output to csv in python

Tags: python, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am a beginner in Python and i need to export my function output in csv/xlsx format.
Please see my code.
I need to print my output of pixel2coord function to csv. Thanks

```
from osgeo import gdal
# Open raster file
ds = gdal.Open('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\datanew\\ndvi_alig_landsat_clipped.img')
# GDAL affine transform parameters, According to gdal documentation xoff/yoff are image left corner, a/e are pixel wight/height and b/d is rotation and is zero if image is north up. 
xoff, a, b, yoff, d, e = ds.GetGeoTransform() 
def pixel2coord(x, y):
    """Returns global coordinates from pixel x, y coords"""   
    xp = a * x + b * y + xoff
    yp = d * x + e * y + yoff
    return(xp, yp)
# get columns and rows of your image from gdalinfo
rows = 15381+1
colms = 15081+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for row in  range(0,rows):
        for col in  range(0,colms): 
            print pixel2coord(col,row)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the code as text with your question

Comment: okay. done that @roganjosh

Comment: I copied the code and pasted it as text @GMB. Thanks

Comment: Is this any different than the generic case of writing a large matrix to a csv? If not, you may find the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module useful.

Comment: my suggestion is to print it as "comma separated value": open a "regular" text file than write numbers on it as string: `file.write("{},{}\n".format(x,y))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of your interest:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file=open("file.csv","w") ## open file in write mode
    for row in  range(0,rows):
        for col in  range(0,colms): 
            x,y = pixel2coord(col,row)
            print "({},{})".format(x,y)
            lat= ## x or y
            long= ## x or y
            file.write("{};{}\n".format(lat,long)) ## write each coordinate comma-separated
```

PS: I'm using european style csv (semicolon separated), if you're american feel free to replace semicolon (inside the string) with comma

Comment: Thanks for the response. This gives the output as individual rows and columns values in the file.csv sheet. I need coordinates where col is longitude and row is latitude.

Comment: I edited the script above: you just have to select "what" is latitude and longitude (in terms of x and y) values returned from your function.